# Conditional Filtering Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two spark Dataframes `Table A - Data` and `Table B - Filter Lookup`. I want to apply a different filter based on a column value in Data (Table A).

Table A - Data

| ID | Col 1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | AA |
| 2 | B | BB |
| 3 | A | AB |
| 4 | A | AC |
| 5 | B | BA |
| 6 | A | AD |
| 7 | B | AB |

Table B - Filter Lookup

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | AA |
| B | BB |
| A | AB |
| B | BA |

The output that I want is:

I don't want the data table to have the col2 values defined in Filter Lookup table. So the output needs to be:

| ID | Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | A | AC |
| 6 | A | AD |
| 7 | B | AB |

Table A could be huge. And I want an efficient way to do it in spark. Also the lookup table can have more types of col1. So I don't want to just limit to two Col1 values (A & B).

Here is what I tried. I am basically applying the filter multiple times depending upon the values of col1. Is there a way to do it in one go without the loop on col1 values.

```
data_col1 = data.select("col1") \
    .na.drop().dropDuplicates().rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()

filter_col1 = filter_lookup.select("col1") \
    .na.drop().dropDuplicates().rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()

result_list = []

for col1 in data_col1:
    if col1 in filter_col1:
        
        col2_list = filter_lookup.filter(f.col("col1") == f.lit(col1)).select("col2").na.drop().dropDuplicates().rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()

        filtered = data\
            .filter(f.col("col2").isin(col2_list)    
                    & f.col("col1") == f.lit(col1))\
            .dropDuplicates()

        result_list.append(filtered)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything ? if yes, can you please add your code to the question ?

Comment: Hi, I have added my attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Just apply ***left anti join*** to take only rows from the left table that don't have any matching rows from the right table:

```
result_df = df_data.join(df_lookup, ['col1', 'col2'], how='leftanti')
result_df.show()
```

---

```
+----+----+---+
|Col1|Col2| ID|
+----+----+---+
|   A|  AC|  4|
|   A|  AD|  6|
|   B|  AB|  7|
+----+----+---+
```